# JPQL order entities by passed IDs to IN clause

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hql, jpql

is possible order entities by IDs which I pass as parameter to IN clause with spring data repository?

For instanse:

```
SELECT e FROM Employee WHERE e.id IN (:employeeIds);
```

and employeeIds = {1,2,3,4,5}

and my List with result from JPARepository will be entities is same order:

```
Employee={id:1, ...}, Employee={id:2, ...}, Employee={id:3, ...}
```

Comment: That's a nice question. Do you know, if it's possible with pure sql?

Comment: @Andronicus I have no idea. I solving this problem at first time, and I need ensure order of I have without post-processing in java

Comment: Is this question still active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on database you are using you can create a table from passed array and join the entity to is, something like that:

```
select e
from (values (1), (2), (3), ...) as t(id)
inner join employee e on t.id = e.id;
```

This can be evaluated as native query:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(
    "select e " +
    "from (values (1), (2), (3), ...) as t(id) " +
    "inner join employee e on t.id = e.id", Employee.class)
    .gerResultList();
```

But as you see you would have to compose query yourself or pass quite a lot od parameters (maybe in loop).